# oauth Chrome Extension Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-extension

Had anyone had any luck getting OAuth between a Google Chrome extension and Google App engine to play nicely (or for that matter anything else?). I have followed all the steps.I have followed through the steps in this [Google Dev tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) and regardless I get redirected to `about:blank` at the end of the handshake process.

I have this code in my extension (cf what is in the tutorial):

```
var baseurl = 'https://my-app.appspot.com';
var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
    'request_url' : baseUrl + '/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken',
    'authorize_url' : baseUrl + '/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
    'access_url' : baseUrl + '/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken',
    'consumer_key' : 'anonymous',
    'consumer_secret' : 'anonymous',
    'scope' : baseUrl,
    'app_name' : 'MyApp'
});
```

...but I do not think this is the issue because I note a similar issue occurs when I use the tutorial's oAuth parameters - I get redirected to a page asking whether I want to grant access to Google Drive and on clicking 'grant access' I get sent to `about:blank` and there seems to be no OAuth token.

Any ideas much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE** Maybe I am ansering my own question - not sure. 
I was also working with the source for the ChromeToPhone extension - my code was based on this for the OAuth google app engine side of things. I tried installing this extension from source and got `about:blank` same issue. So then I went to this extension on the Extension App Store and the same thing occurs with that too. So maybe my Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.26 beta-m) is broken? Does this happen for anyone else or is my Chrome installation broken somehow?

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

The Chrome Extensions documentation for the `web_accessible_resources` manifest property [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html#web_accessible_resources) mention that:

> A navigation from a web origin to an extension resource will be blocked unless the resource is listed as web accessible.

And then lower:

> Resources inside of packages using `manifest_version` 2 or above are blocked by default, and must be whitelisted for use via this property.

Apparently that last part was added as part of the Chrome 31 release.

### Solution

The solution is to set `web_accessible_resources` in your extension manifest to an array containing your OAuth handshake completion URL like this:

```
{
    "web_accessible_resources": [
         "oauth2/oauth2.html"
    ]
}
```

### Sources

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310870#c4

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html#web_accessible_resources

Comment: This worked for me (with some changes to the exact filename).

Comment: Glad I could help! The filename applies when you are using [OAuth2.js](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) by Boris Smus since I assume that's the most common OAuth use method in Chrome Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Code from google dev website tutorial seems to work on chrome v30, but not v31.

Similar issue if one tries the chrometophone app from the WebStore.

Can only conclude that something has changed in Chrome that means that oauth js libraries provided on the tutorial no longer working - raised as potential issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310870). See what happens.