# OAuth with Chrome extension and YouTube

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth, youtube-api

I am trying to port a Chrome extension - not developed by me - to the new Manifest v2. Basically with v2 you can't use inline js, so I moved some code into dedicated files and added a few lines of code to make popup and background talk as they did before. I'm doing this to understand how the "OAuth dance" works, and develop my own app in the future. Right now the problem I face is this: the extension opens a page asking user's authorization at interacting with his YouTube account. When I confirm, the necessary tokens should be passed back to the extension, and the auth page should self close. Instead, I'm left with an empty page. Something goes wrong, but I've been trying to debug the code for two days without any success.

Additional details

I am using a developer key that I generated at google dashboard, not the one I found in the svn of the original extension, in case anyone wondered.

[Here](http://youtube-feed-chrome-extension.googlecode.com/svn/) is the original extension code, and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljx4cghj7495vw9/YTPlaylistManager.zip) the one modified by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Chrome 31 blocks callbacks unless you add the return page in the manifest, that's why I always landed on a blank page instead. Found the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553712/oauth-chrome-extension-google-app-engine) Stackoverflow question. Basically you have to edit your manifest.json like this:

```
{
    "web_accessible_resources": [
         "path/to/callback_page.html"
    ]
}
```